# Laravel getModelByTableName() function work locally but doesn't work on the server

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following function written in php\Laravel

```
public static function getModelByTablename($tableName) {
    $model = new ('App\Models\\'.Str::studly(strtolower(Str::singular($tableName))));
    return $model;
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9WMz.png)

it works fine on my computer(windows 10) but on the server it doesn't work and give me the following error

> syntax error, unexpected '('

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: No, I've read it but it does not work. any other solutions

Comment: Let's see your entire file. Are you sure included all the necessary classes with the `use` directive for this line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be this: (not tested)

```php
public static function getModelByTablename($tableName) {
    $model = "App\Models\\" . str($tableName)->singular()->studly();
    return new $model();
}
```

(`str` function is only available on laravel 9, otherwise use `Str::of` with the correct import)

Comment: I am using Str with the correct import and it is working good on my local environment 
your code gives an error undefined function str

Comment: if `str()` is undefined, use `Str::of()` instead. Remember to `use Illuminate\Support\Str;` at the top of the document.

Comment: can you explain to me what was happening? because it was working locally

Comment: I have no Idea, its probably some problem with a different PHP or Laravel Version locally.